# What Typescript type to set for setState passed to the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some Parent components like:

```
const ParentOne = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<{ one: boolean }>({ one: false });
...omit
  return (
    <>
      <Child setErr={setError} name={"one"} />
    </>
  );
};

const ParentTwo = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<{ one: boolean; two: boolean }>({
    one: false,
    two: false,
  });
...omit
  return (
    <>
      <Child setErr={setError} name={"one"} />
      <Child setErr={setError} name={"two"} />
    </>
  );
};
```

and so on with different numbers of Child components and different

```
const[...] =  useState<{ one: boolean; two: boolean; ...n: boolean }>({
        one: false,
        two: false,
        ...,
        n: false    
      });
```

This is my Child component:

```
const Child: FC<IChild> = ({ setErr, name }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setErr((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: true }));
  };
  return <button onClick={handleClick}/>;
};
```

I dont know which type to set for setErr, because useState has different generics for diffrent Parent components. I tried like this:

```
interface IChild {
  setErr: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{ [key: string]: boolean }>>;
  name: string;
}
```

But in each Parent component, setErr requires an exact match of the type in IChild with the generic in useState

Comment: I hope this will help me get an answer to the question)

Comment: Yup, it did. :-)

Comment: It works, thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truthful type of your `setErr` prop with `Child` as written is:

```typescript
type ErrorSetter = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{[key: string]: boolean}>>;
```

I see two options:

1. Use `Child` as written and use a type assertion on `setError` (in one of a couple of ways, more below).
2. Use a custom hook and simplify `Child`

My preference would be for #2, but let's look at each of them:

### Using `Child` as written with type assertions

So if we use that error setter, we have:

```typescript
type ErrorSetter = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{[key: string]: boolean}>>;
interface IChild {
  setErr: ErrorSetter;
  name: string;
}
```

How to use that without constantly writing `as`?

Largely, we don't, but you might do it just once per parent component:

```typescript
const ParentTwo = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState({
    one: false,
    two: false,
  });
  const setErr = setError as ErrorSetter;
//
  return (
    <>
      <Child setErr={setErr} name="one" />
      <Child setErr={setErr} name="two" />
    </>
  );
};
```

That's reasonably convenient, and leaves `Child` unchanged, although as is often (always?) the case with type assertions, it's not entirely typesafe.

### Use a custom hook

But I would lean toward using a custom hook and simplifying `Child`. The hook is:

```typescript
const useErrorState = <T,>(initial: T): [T, (name: keyof T) => void] => {
  const [error, realSetError] = useState(initial);
  const setError = useCallback(
    (name: keyof T) => {
      realSetError(prev => ({...prev, [name]: true}));
    },
    []
  );
  return [error, setError];
};
```

Then you'd use it like this if you don't need `setErr` to be stable:

```typescript
const ParentTwo = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useErrorState({
    one: false,
    two: false,
  });
//
  return (
    <>
      <Child setErr={() => setError("one")} />
      <Child setErr={() => setError("two")} />
    </>
  );
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgUQE6pKgylAhlRGAXhgB4AVAGgD4AKASzHqntwBsAuGcgSi4G0qMWmFwBbRFwDWiAJ4gAZtx7FqMAG4h6AEwC6qmAG8AUDBihIsfonSZKMVInZZEUNBlT6SCRDnyIGJhZ2HgBuU3NwaBgkN1tUYngkAGF2NgAjXGApWgizEXFJGBl5JV4DEzMqhyc2FziPWgAHR3UDWkMAOm6WxHV7flEJXS4oVDhEAF8eMLyYSco5-l0I2bNHKDhUMBhrePtY90xdcMnw43oxJsxYACUnYCh7QxgAMWT7Hz8CT5S0zOy8xgCgwYhgACJHFkoODzowCKgFFlCABJZIAC3obG0Rgih3QXFoKiIak0OlOxmMFmiGKx2i471IaMx2LUJA6MVc7nmxLUlUilhg6NwYG0bEQyTY9EB7N5uOq+NQETOEQ2Wx2pHScCgUHAMHAkulUiIhmFovFhuykwA9NRTudqbAAAq4RxgKAAeTAhFlFQijt2Ng8By58S8SRQ8W+ARe4CKSLYSB54Wt1tVrnVwjmpGoczMpFp2M5DRNRIMiswtHBcfBPEmMFt2cbZlmKqpUWdrsQ7vIAHcQIkyyT5QLontg8Wjp5Ej4p9GOnM41wE0hFtUoP3l+xV8rZqn05ttlnqjm82RCzjFaW5RXUFWa3WG7nqvmL5P0Nfy6HGuCNyBa-WzZVKQQGtuEQA)

...or like this if you do because you want to avoid `Child` re-rendering (this would assume `Child` uses `React.memo` or [in a class component] `PureComponent` or `shouldComponentUpdate`):

```typescript
const ParentTwo = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useErrorState({
    one: false,
    two: false,
  });
  const setErrorOne = useCallback(() => setError("one"), []);
  const setErrorTwo = useCallback(() => setError("two"), []);
//
  return (
    <>
      <Child setErr={setErrorOne} />
      <Child setErr={setErrorTwo} />
    </>
  );
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgUQE6pKgylAhlRGAXhgB4AVAGgD4AKASzHqntwBsAuGcgSi4G0qMWmFwBbRFwDWiAJ4gAZtx7FqMAG4h6AEwC6qmAG8AUDBihIsfonSZKMVInZZEUNBlT6SCRDnyIGJhZ2HgBuU3NwaBgkN1tUYngkAGF2NgAjXGApWgizEXFJGBl5JV4DEzMqhyc2FziPWgAHR3UDWkMAOm6WxHV7flEJXS4oVDhEAF8eMLyYSco5-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-aDq21TtrhQGoARDSYCBA4jlUpAMWO4RAA)